# How to use range value in UpdateCursor in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update

I am trying to add range value in attribute tables by using `UpdateCursor` module of data access (da).

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
sql = "رقم_المعاملة = '307'"
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyr, "*", sql)
for row in cursor:
    for x in range(1, 6, 1):
        row[5] = x
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

When I run this script, the result is 5 in all attributes. But need the value by range. For example, 1 in row 1, 2 in row 2, ... and 6 in row 6.

Comment: It's generally unwise to use a wildcard in the column list of cursors, since there are sometimes phantom columns in the resulting list. Instead, explicitly list your field names. Your processing  loops are incorrectly structured to process each row once (instead it will make five updates to each row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import arcpy, itertools

fc_to_update = r'C:\data.gdb\features'
field_to_update = 'somefieldname'

alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
repeatingGenerator = itertools.cycle(alist) #https://stackoverflow.com/a/45037522/6936582

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc_to_update, field_to_update) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = next(repeatingGenerator)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and this coding. Its work.

Answer (score 2):

the second loop (on the range) in your script will run to its end at every row, this is why you end up with the maximum value of your range in each row value.

If you just need an incremental value, then you simply need to initialize a counter. If this counter has to be limited by a maximum value, then you can use a modulo operator (%).

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    i=1
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = i #I assume taht your field is the first of the list
        i=i%6 + 1 #this exemple gives values of 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2...
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import arcpy, itertools

fc_to_update = r'C:\data.gdb\features'
field_to_update = 'somefieldname'

alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
repeatingGenerator = itertools.cycle(alist) #https://stackoverflow.com/a/45037522/6936582

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc_to_update, field_to_update) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = next(repeatingGenerator)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```